# Cannot zero-fill a 1TB Harddrive or Mount

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, disk, format

The Ubuntu graphical disk utility continously throws the following error:

> Error erasing device: Error doing BLKGETSIZE64 iotctl on /dev/sdb:
>   Inappropriate ioctl for device (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Each time I attempt to overwrite to zeros. The disk is undetectable on  `fdisk` and when I enter the disk path `fdisk /dev/sdb` and list unpartitioned memory it says

```
Unpartitioned space /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4107276288 bytes, 8022024 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Start     End Sectors  Size
 2048 8024071 8022024  3.8G
```

on a 1 Terabyte Harddrive.
How do I convert the entire HardDrive to Free Space?

**EDIT:** The graphical utility lists the file system on the drive as unknown so, why is 3.8GB unpartitioned?

**EDIT2:** The output of `fdisk -l` as requested

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 931DB495-F781-4E35-A33D-029E341109D3

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1026047    1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1026048    1288191     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     1288192 1675677487 1674389296 798.4G Microsoft basic dat
/dev/sda4  1926920192 1928663039    1742848   851M Windows recovery en
/dev/sda5  1928663040 1953523711   24860672  11.9G Windows recovery en
/dev/sda6  1675677696 1910360063  234682368 111.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  1910360064 1926920191   16560128   7.9G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 7.9 GiB, 8478261248 bytes, 16559104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: Are you sure that sdb represents 1 Tb drive? Please add output of `sudo fdisk -l` to the question.

Comment: I've posted the output above.

Comment: I dual boot ubuntu and windows 10 hence /dev/sda

Comment: As far I can understand *sda* is 1 Tb and you use it to boot Windows and Ubuntu. Do you really need to delete its contents? How many hard drives, SSDs or hybrid drives your system have?

Comment: No no Dev/sda is my laptops internal hardrive sdb is an external hard drive I've been unable to format

Comment: Then make sure that external drive is normally powered (use USB Y cable to have high current) and then retry. Sometimes GNOME Disks is unable to format drives (especially on 14.04 LTS if I remember correctly).

Comment: The Power supply is irrelevant, I can hear the drive spin up and its detectable on the  graphical disk utility but NOT on fdisk.